# PHP Date Relative Formats last day of +X days

Tags: php, datetime

I'm playing around with the PHP date relative formats and trying to get the 20th of the current month or 20th of the month of a given date.

I was hoping to use something like `first day of this month +20 days`, but it still returns the first of the current month.

I know I could use the `modify()` method twice, but I still hope there is a way to avoid this :-)

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the parser reads the words `"first day of this month"`, and then immediately returns the first day of the current month without any regard for what comes after: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#118062.
There is also quite a lot of explained exceptions discussed on the linked page as well.

Usually, in my experience, the best thing to do is avoid the relative syntax as much as possible and use the DateTime(Immutable) interface. Workings with dates and times is hard enough with a good interface, nevermind with a badly documented feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = date('Y-m-1'); //returns first day of current month date('Y-5-1'); for any  month given
echo date("D Y-m-d",strtotime($d.' +19 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use twice modify with relative formats, you can use modify and format.
I think that's better to understand too.

```
//As an example, one day in November 2020
$date = new DateTime('2020-11-15');
  
$date->modify($date->format('Y-m-20'));

var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-11-20 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```